# VSCode - Is it possible to always show the current function name or scope somewhere at the top?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It would be very useful for editing JavaScript or TypeScript to always see the current function name at the top (like Xcode does for example). Sometimes when editing a long function (or having larger parts of the screen obscured with the console), it would be very useful to be able to verify that I'm actually in the correct function / to know in which function I am at the moment.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 34):

Another way to "pin" the current function definition to the top of the editor is with `sticky scroll`.

> Sticky scroll is a feature that shows the current scope at the top of
> the view port.

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_71.md#sticky-scroll

This was introduced in v1.70 and is still undergoing improvements.  And is currently under an `experimental` setting so expect some changes.

> In v1.71 it will no longer be "experimental" and so the setting will
> become:
>
> ```
> Editor > Sticky Scroll: Enabled
> ```

Until v1.71 comes out here is the current information:

First enable this setting: `Editor > Experimental > Sticky Scroll: Enabled`

There will be a toggle command to show/hide the sticky scroll lines: `editor.action.toggleStickyScroll`

[image: sticky scroll demo]

Clicking on that sticky function definition will take you to the top of the function.

Control/command click in the sticky scroll will take you to the definition.

Another demo from the [v1.70 Release Notes: Sticky Scroll](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_70.md#sticky-scroll)

[image: sticky scroll demo2]

Currently you can modify the background color and shadow color with these `colorCustomizations` in your `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorStickyScroll.background": "#444",
  "editorStickyScrollHover.background": "#f00",
  "scrollbar.shadow": "#fff9"      // with a little opacity for the dropShadow
},
```

There is a related setting:

```
Editor > Experimental > Sticky Scroll: Max Line Count
Defines the maximum number of sticky lines to show
```

Default for above is `5`.

Comment: Note: VSCode 1.71, no longer experimental: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/158728/files

Comment: Of interest, with VSCode 1.72 (Sept. 2022): "[When no document symbol provider use the folding model for the sticky scroll](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157165)"

Comment: Also of interest (VSCode 1.77, March 2023): "[Add a command to reveal line shown in sticky scroll](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/169107)"

Answer (score 6):

This was added with VS Code 1.26. It is called [`breadcrumbs`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_breadcrumbs)

Breadcrumbs are enabled by default for languages with advanced support. This includes JS/TS, html, and css out of the box. Extensions can add support for more languages

Comment: Didn't notice it until see you answer, save my day!!

Comment: For those who are new, the default key binding to show Breadcrumbs is ctrl+shift+. (dot)